# Issue Installing Talend,No Response

Tags: installation, etl, talend, data-migration, talend-mdm

[image]

issue is that while configuring and opening the Talend is giving no response and no hovering type scene is happening during mouse pointer will take on  i agree options whenever i'm opening no response on clicking to a I Agree button

I'm installing this on Mac OS

Answer (score 0):

Since the talend runs on Eclipse base, check the logs in the installation directory.